# If a tangent drawn from a point on the director circle of ellipse $E = \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$, the chord...

Tags: circles, elliptic-curves

[image]

Actually I am not getting the question, if the tangent is drawn from one point on the director circle of the ellipse itself then where is the chord of contact.
Can you help me with a diagram???

Comment: Does [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CNzx.png) help?